# Why is the (seemingly) unrelated div re-painted in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, google-chrome-devtools, html-rendering

Could anyone help me understand why the scroll container on the RIGHT gets repainted when scrolling the container on the LEFT?

Here is the gif illustrating the issue:

[image: Strange re-painting]

Notice that the right layer is currently highlighted in the layers panel and it is being re-painted as I scroll on the left.
This illustrates the problem I am having in a much larger html - Update Layers Tree and Composition become the main bottleneck.

The layout is pretty simple, see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5owta80/). There are two absolutely positioned divs, inside each there is a scrolling div with some content.

Tested on Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Mac 10.10.5, Chrome 61.0.3159.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit) on Mac.

```
<div class="left panel">
  <div class="inner inside-left">
    <p>asdad</p><p>asdad</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="right panel">
  <div class="inner inside-right">
    <p>asdad</p><p>asdad</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be a bug already reported on https://crbug.com

Comment: Which version of Chrome? I can't seem to reproduce it on Chromium 57.0.2987.98 in Linux and Chrome Canary 61.0.3159.0 in Windows.

Comment: @MrLister Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit), on Mac 10.10.5

Comment: @MrLister Same issue on  61.0.3159.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit) on Mac